# Field to return a result from GET request on remote python server

Tags: python, server, get, raspberry-pi

I'm facing a problem while performing a "GET" request from postman into my server on raspberry pi 4 that is running a python code...

the Error i'm facing is:

`'int' object is not callable The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a int.`

### This Codes job is to calculate a stream of values that are coming from a sensor and then return their average, but whenever I try it, it always gave me this error..
#Note that its working fine on Pycharm but it's no on the request.

The python Script is:

```
def oxygin():
   result = "Result is: "
   print("\nSparkFun MAX3010x Photodetector - Example 5\n")
   sensor = qwiic_max3010x.QwiicMax3010x()

if sensor.begin() == False:
    print("The Qwiic MAX3010x device isn't connected to the system. Please check your connection", \
        file=sys.stderr)
    return
else:
    print("The Qwiic MAX3010x is connected.")

print("Place your index finger on the sensor with steady pressure.")

if sensor.setup() == False:
    print("Device setup failure. Please check your connection", \
        file=sys.stderr)
    return
else:
    print("Setup complete.")

sensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A) # Turn Red LED to low to indicate sensor is running
sensor.setPulseAmplitudeGreen(0) # Turn off Green LED

RATE_SIZE = 4 # Increase this for more averaging. 4 is good.
rates = list(range(RATE_SIZE)) # list of heart rates
rateSpot = 0
lastBeat = 0 # Time at which the last beat occurred
beatsPerMinute = 0.00
OxiAvg = 0
samplesTaken = 0 # Counter for calculating the Hz or read rate
startTime = millis() # Used to calculate measurement rate

while True:

    irValue = sensor.getIR()
    samplesTaken += 1
    if sensor.checkForBeat(irValue) == True:

        # We sensed a beat!
        #print('')
        delta = ( millis() - lastBeat )
        lastBeat = millis() 

        beatsPerMinute = 60 / (delta / 1000.0)
        beatsPerMinute = round(beatsPerMinute,1)

        if beatsPerMinute < 255 and beatsPerMinute > 20:
            rateSpot += 1
            rateSpot %= RATE_SIZE # Wrap variable
            rates[rateSpot] = beatsPerMinute # Store this reading in the array

            # Take average of readings
            OxiAvg = 0

            for x in range(0, RATE_SIZE):
                OxiAvg += rates[x]
            OxiAvg /= RATE_SIZE
            OxiAvg = round(OxiAvg)

    Hz = round(float(samplesTaken) / ( ( millis() - startTime ) / 1000.0 ) , 2)
    if (samplesTaken > 1000) == 1:
        result = str(OxiAvg)
        #return str(OxiAvg)
        #print('SpO2=', (beatAvg+15) , '%\t')

return result
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should return a string object, not an int object

Replace the following line:

```
return result
```

with:

```
return str(result)
```